# system.import script not getting executed in Angular

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have created an Angular2 application in IntelliJ and Play Framework. Following code is giving error

```
<script>
                System.import('assets/app/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
        </script>
```

Error:
`Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-ol8t6QICwIETK9dhrEwBShFCgKGwmDHZW/nmyLH+rYs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Answer (score 0):

Inline JavaScript is not permitted in a html  block. Your best bet is to move that code into a new .js file and then call that file from the  block.

```
<script src="newscript.js"></script>
```

And in newscript.js

```
System.import('assets/app/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

Checkout [this reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) for more  details on why an inline script is not permitted.

Comment: still same error - `Error: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'".

  Instantiating http://localhost:9000/assets/app/main.js`